# Batch file Loop through list

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am still pretty new in this field so I apologize ahead of time if there is incorrect verbiage used. I am looking for a way to have my batch file loop and repeat the same process over once completed only using a different number for %3 from a list of numbers. The list of numbers for %3 are less than 100 so I do not mind writing them out in the Batch file it just becomes tedious waiting for the command to finish and writing the next number. Also these numbers are not in sequence (i.e. 1-100) but scattered (i.e. 2, 6, 21, 48). Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO ==============STORE #%3================ >>EM_Push.log   
ECHO %date% >>EM_Push.log 
ECHO %time% >>EM_Push.log
IF EXIST d:\micros\res\em\transport\send\0%3\*.mpz goto start  
IF NOT EXIST d:\micros\res\en\transport\send\0%3\*.mpz goto nofile


:START 
ECHO ---------Mapping Drive------------ >>EM_Push.log
net use s: /d
net use s: \\10.16.%3.101\d$ /user:%1 %2 >>EM_Push.log  
IF NOT EXIST s:\micros ECHO POSSIBLE NETWORK ISSUE >>EM_Push.log   
IF NOT EXIST s:\micros goto end

ECHO ----------Copy Package from EM to Store %3----------- >>EM_Push.log  
copy d:\micros\res\em\transport\send\0%3\*.mpz s:\micros\res\em\transport\receive >>EM_Push.log
IF NOT EXIST d:\micros\res\em\transport\send\0%3\archive md d:\micros\res\em\transport\send\0%3\archive
move d:\micros\res\em\transport\send\0%3\*.mpz d:\micros\res\em\transport\send\0%3\archive >>EM_Push.log

ECHO --------Deploy Package-------------- >>EM_Push.log
psexec \\10.16.%3.101 -u %1 -p %2 d:\micros\res\em\bin\receive.exe >>EM_Push.log
psexec \\10.16.%3.101 -u %1 -p %2 d:\micros\res\em\bin\deployment.exe >>EM_Push.log

REM ECHO ---------Exit41 Update------------- >>EM_Push.log
REM IF EXIST s:\exit41\commands\pagepull.exe psexec \\10.16.%3.101 -u %1 -p %2 d:\exit41\commands\pagepull.exe >>EM_Push.log
REM IF EXIST s:\exit41\commands\pagepull.exe ECHO Done! >>EM_Push.log
REM IF NOT EXIST s:\exit41\commands\pagepull.exe ECHO Not subscribed to Exit41 >>EM_Push.log

ECHO ----------Copy Confirmation from Stor %3 to EM----------- >>EM_Push.log
IF NOT EXIST s:\micros\res\em\transport\send\*.mpz ECHO RECEIVE PACKET NOT AVAILABLE >>EM_Push.log
IF NOT EXIST s:\micros\res\em\transport\send\*.mpz goto end
copy s:\micros\res\em\transport\send\*.mpz d:\micros\res\em\transport\receive >>EM_Push.log
IF NOT EXIST s:\micros\res\em\transport\send\archive md s:\micros\res\em\transport\send\archive
move s:\micros\res\em\transport\send\*.mpz s:\micros\res\em\transport\send\archive >>EM_Push.log

goto end

:NOFILE
ECHO NO UPDATES FOR THIS STORE  >>EM_Push.log

:END
net use s: /d >>EM_Push.log
ECHO==============END STORE #%3============= >>EM_Push.log
```

Comment: Do you have made a typing mistake on line 7 in directory name `en` as everywhere else the directory is `em`?

Comment: Open a command prompt window, run in this window `for /?`  and read all the help pages output for this command. There are also thousands of examples on Stack Overflow which uses command __FOR__ to read something like numbers from list file line by line and process commands with the read data. Or do you specify all the numbers as third parameter, i.e. `"2 6 21 48"` in which case also command __FOR__ is the solution. Or do you run the batch file with `username password 2 6 21 48` which could be processed also with __FOR__ after using twice command __SHIFT__.

Comment: One more hint: `net use s: \\10.16.%3.101\d$ /user:%1 %2 /persistent:no` is advisable here or Windows stores all network shares temporarily (up to the deletion) in Windows registry (for automatic reconnect on next logon) which does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just call your script several times, using your numbers one after the other.

Assuming, your numbers are in `numbers.txt`:

```
for /f %%i in (numbers.txt) do (
  call :process %1 %2 %%i
)
goto :eof

:process
REM here goes your script
```

your `numbers.txt` should look like:

```
2
6
21
48
...
```

Comment: Hi Stephan, after reading about my options a txt file seems the best way to go. Now i've read through the help pages output from command and still don't quite understand where this would go in the batch file. Also will the loop know to stop at the last number?

Comment: The For command itself does this go at the complete beginning of the script before @Echo OFF? Also when running the running the command from prompt now that the variable is in place of %3 do I use something else in this section?

Comment: in principle yes. But some common tasks should be moved before (like `net use` - no point in doing it multiple times). This can improve performance noticable. You could leave `@echo off` behind, but I would consider it a "common task". Simply spoken, my code does "for every line in the file (`%%i`) do something with the content of this line"